# HTTPS link fetch issue

Tags: php, https, request, http-status-code-301

i have been trying for the last several days to fetch a request from a website but no success.
I keep getting error 301.
Is anyone able to help me grab the content of this page: https://pre.corrupt-net.org/search.php?search=Lasse_Stefanz-Bara_Du-SE-CD-FLAC-1995-LoKET

I am looking forward to your reply.

EDIT:
This is the php function I've used:

```
function http_request(
    $verb = 'GET',             /* HTTP Request Method (GET and POST supported) */
    $ip,                       /* Target IP/Hostname */
    $port = 80,                /* Target TCP port */
    $uri = '/',                /* Target URI */
    $getdata = array(),        /* HTTP GET Data ie. array('var1' => 'val1', 'var2' => 'val2') */
    $postdata = array(),       /* HTTP POST Data ie. array('var1' => 'val1', 'var2' => 'val2') */
    $cookie = array(),         /* HTTP Cookie Data ie. array('var1' => 'val1', 'var2' => 'val2') */
    $custom_headers = array(), /* Custom HTTP headers ie. array('Referer: http://localhost/ */
    $timeout = 1000,           /* Socket timeout in milliseconds */
    $req_hdr = false,          /* Include HTTP request headers */
    $res_hdr = false           /* Include HTTP response headers */
    )
{
    $ret = '';
    $verb = strtoupper($verb);
    $cookie_str = '';
    $getdata_str = count($getdata) ? '?' : '';
    $postdata_str = '';
    foreach ($getdata as $k => $v)
        $getdata_str .= urlencode($k) .'='. urlencode($v);
    foreach ($postdata as $k => $v)
        $postdata_str .= urlencode($k) .'='. urlencode($v) .'&';
    foreach ($cookie as $k => $v)
        $cookie_str .= urlencode($k) .'='. urlencode($v) .'; ';
    $crlf = "\r\n";
    $req = $verb .' '. $uri . $getdata_str .' HTTP/1.1' . $crlf;
    $req .= 'Host: '. $ip . $crlf;
    $req .= 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/3.6.12' . $crlf;
    $req .= 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' . $crlf;
    $req .= 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5' . $crlf;
    $req .= 'Accept-Encoding: deflate' . $crlf;
    $req .= 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7' . $crlf;
    foreach ($custom_headers as $k => $v)
        $req .= $k .': '. $v . $crlf;
    if (!empty($cookie_str))
        $req .= 'Cookie: '. substr($cookie_str, 0, -2) . $crlf;
    if ($verb == 'POST' && !empty($postdata_str)){
        $postdata_str = substr($postdata_str, 0, -1);
        $req .= 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' . $crlf;
        $req .= 'Content-Length: '. strlen($postdata_str) . $crlf . $crlf;
        $req .= $postdata_str;
    }   
    else $req .= $crlf;
    if ($req_hdr)
        $ret .= $req;
    if (($fp = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr)) == false)
        return "Error $errno: $errstr\n";
    stream_set_timeout($fp, 0, $timeout * 1000);
    fputs($fp, $req);
    while ($line = fgets($fp)) $ret .= $line;
    fclose($fp);
    if (!$res_hdr)
        $ret = substr($ret, strpos($ret, "\r\n\r\n") + 4);
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use something like curl?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, [301 is not an "error" as such](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301), it indicates that you are being redirected. You need to parse the response headers, take the value of the `Location:` header (which the HTTP protocol specification requires be present in a redirect response) and request that URI as well.

Secondly, the function above does not appear to provide any support for accessing HTTPS URLs. You need the OpenSSL extension installed for your PHP instance to do this, and you also need to actually call it some how. You could use the above function to do so by passing `ssl://` or `tls://` in front of the address in the `$ip` parameter, but you cannot simply pass the IP.

Thirdly, the usual way to do things like this is with the [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) extension. You would do something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://pre.corrupt-net.org/search.php?search=Lasse_Stefanz-Bara_Du-SE-CD-FLAC-1995-LoKET'); // Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); // Follow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Get the result from the execution

if (($result = curl_exec($ch)) === FALSE) { // Execute the request
  echo "cURL failed! Error: ".curl_error($ch);
} else {
  echo "Success! Result: $result";
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Alternatively, if cURL is not available or you don't want to use it for some reason, you could have go with [my HTTPRequest class](http://download.networkm.net/code/php/class.httprequest.1.3.php.tar.gz), which is PHP4 compliant and requires no extensions (apart from OpenSSL for HTTPS requests). Documented(ish) in comments at the top of the script. You would do something like this:

```
$request = new httprequest(); // Create an object

// Set the request URL
if (!$request->setRequestURL('https://pre.corrupt-net.org/search.php?search=Lasse_Stefanz-Bara_Du-SE-CD-FLAC-1995-LoKET')) echo "Failed! Error: ".$request->getLastErrorStr()."<br>\r\n";
// Send the request
if (!$request->sendRequest()) echo "Failed! Error: ".$request->getLastErrorStr()."<br>\r\n";

echo "Success! Result: ".$request->getResponseBodyData(TRUE);
```

On a side note, a lot of the Scene PreDB managers/providers are not too keen on automated scraping, and you may get yourself banned...

Comment: thank you for your reply. I've tried your curl code already, trying to send all the headers and i still got no response. I get Success but the response variable is empty. I will post the feedback of the class you've posted.
EDIT: i get the same result with curl and with the httprequest. It is strange because i can fetch the file lastpred.php just using the standard way:

    $string = file_get_contents("http://pre.corrupt-net.org/lastpred.php");